# Configure domain for 2 IP

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing

I am doing a service that for each user creates subdomain. So for example I have 2 servers, each with own IP. For example www.example.com is only one IP. But all others should have proj1.example.com (1 IP), proj2.example.com (2 IP).

What should I put into DNS? Set all IPs as A record?

What best practices for this on big projects with hundreds of servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, this is accomplished with two A records pointing to the same name.